# convert json to html with Python

Tags: python

I've understood the method used in post [How can I render an html from a JSON-like string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63066903/12214867)

I guess I can use a for loop to create a bunch of elements as well as go through each of them, setting attributes and `textContent`.

This code snippet

```
f1=open('./notes.html', 'a')
num_attributes = 0
num_insert = 0
for i in json_arr:
    if len(i) == 2:
        attr_color = i['attributes']['color']
        content = '<p><span style="color:' + attr_color + ';">'+i['insert']+'</span></p>'
    else:
        content = '<p><br></p>'
    f1.write(content + "\n")
f1.close()
```

is to convert the following json (click [here](https://onlinegdb.com/SJYtEEdeP) to get the complete list)

```
[{'attributes': {'color': '#ff0084'},
  'insert': 'Hello everyone, welcome to class..'},
 {'insert': '\n\n\n'},
 {'attributes': {'color': '#dc4d50'}, 'insert': '-I often go walk.'}]
```

to an html.

```html
<p><span style="color:#ff0084;">Hello everyone, welcome to class..</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#dc4d50;">-I often go walk.</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#20b69d;">-I often go for a walk.</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#20b69d;">-I often take a walk.</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#dc4d50;">-I often go eat out.</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#20b69d;">-I often eat out.</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#dc4d50;">-Not usual meet my coworks after work.</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#20b69d;">-I hardly{Rarely} meet my coworkers after work.</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#dc4d50;">-We usually eating out together.</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#20b69d;">-We usually eat out together.</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#dc4d50;">-The feel is relaxing.</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#20b69d;">-The feeling is relaxing.</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#dc4d50;">-What do we need take with us?</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#20b69d;">-What do we need </span></p><p><span style="color:#424242;">to</span></p><p><span style="color:#20b69d;"> take with us?</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#dc4d50;">-We don't swimming.</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#20b69d;">-We don't swim.</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#20b69d;">-We won't be swimming.</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#dc4d50;">-We need to food.</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#20b69d;">-We need to take some food.</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#dc4d50;">-Anything activity?</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#20b69d;">-Are we going to be doing any activities?</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#dc4d50;">-We don't need to take tent.</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#20b69d;">-We don't need to take a tent.</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#20b69d;">-We don't need to take tents.</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#9952fd;">-We need to take some sun lotion.</span></p><p><br></p><p><span style="color:#9952fd;">-We don't need to take boots.</span></p><p><br></p>
```

The code works the way as expected. I'd just like to know whether my code is Pythonic. If not, how do I improve it?

Comment: Does it work the way it should?

Comment: @Mast 
The code works the way as expected. I'd just like to know whether my code is Pythoneer. If not, how do I improve it.

Comment: _Missing Review Context: Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with enough code and / or context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site._ This is the closure category since you describe this as a snippet. We need to see the full code.